WooCommerce change sign up now text for subscription products
I'm trying to change the 'sign up now' text on a single product page. I'm using Woo Subscription plugin and this hook:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'membership_join_now_button_text', 1 );

function membership_join_now_button_text($default) {
  if ( get_the_ID() == 585048 ) {
    return __( 'JOIN NOW', 'woocommerce' );
  } else {
    return $default;
  }
}

The hook works well when the product doesn't have a subscription, but when sub is turned on it overrides  the text with 'sign up now'. I wasn't able to find a way to edit the button text on the documentation...is there a specific hook I can use?
I tried using the default woocommerce hook for single product pages.

Try to increase the hook priority from 1 to 99000 for example, like: add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'membership_join_now_button_text', 99000 );
